# How to do a significance test without the standard deviation?

Tags: statistics

I do an experiment twice, each time with 1000 trials. In the first run, I get 450/1000 positives and in the second run, I get 485/1000 positives.

Is there any way to test if these results represent a significant difference? I know how to test if I have the standard deviation, but what can I do without it?

I was thinking if I split up one of the experiments into 10 runs of 100 trials, that would give me 10 slices and I could calculate a standard deviation from that perhaps?

Thank you!

Comment: The standard deviation is $\le \sqrt{(1000)(1/4)}$ and probably not too far from there.

Answer (score 0):

You want to test $H_0: \theta_1 = \theta_2$ against
$H_0: \theta_1 \ne \theta_2$, where $\theta_1$ is the
probability of a positive on the first run and $\theta_2$
for the second run.

Let $X_1$ be the number of positives in the first run
and $\hat \theta_1 = X_1/n_1 = 450/1000$ estimate $\theta_1$;
similarly for the second run with subscripts 2.

Assuming normality (totally justified with sample sizes of 1000),
a reasonable test statistic is $z = (\hat \theta_1 - \hat \theta_2)/d,$
where $d^2 = \hat \theta_1(1 - \hat \theta_1)/n_1 +
\hat \theta_2(1 - \hat \theta_2)/n_2.$ Under $H_0$ the
test statistic has a standard normal distribution. So $H_0$
is rejected at the 5% level if $|z| > 1.96.$

In a quick calculation (which you should verify exactly), I got $|z| \approx 1.6.$

Because $\hat \theta_1$ and $\hat \theta_2$ are both 'about' 1/2.
a reasonable estimate of the variance of EACH is $(1/2)^2/1000$
(and an upper bound, as in the Comment by @AndreNicolas),
and a reasonable estimate of the variance of the DIFFERENCE
$(\hat \theta_1 - \hat \theta_2)$ in the numerator is twice this, so the estimated standard
deviation of the difference is $d \approx  0.0224,$ which
is remarkably close to the 'standard error' $d$ in my computation.

Intuitively, the absolute value of the numerator of $z$ is .035,
which is less than twice $d$. Roughly speaking, one rejects
at the 5% level only if the magnitude of the difference exceeds twice its standard
error.